# Creating tumbnails with PHP for differnet formats

Tags: php, gd

So i a did this script which create tumbnails on the fly with php and it is working fine, but these files that i am createing tumbnails for are being uploaded from the user. Which i have enough validation to know which type of image it is being uploaded. The allowed once are (**JPG PNG GIF**) no i have created this script above.

```
if (pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'png'){
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($basePath.'/'.$fileName);
                $width = imagesx($img);
                $height = imagesx($img);

                //Calculateing tumbnails size
                $newWidth = 100;
                $newHeight = floor($height*(100/$width));

                //Create a new tempoary image
                $tmpImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);

                imagecopyresized($tmpImage,$img,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);

                imagepng($tmpImage,$pathToTumb.'/'.$fileName);
            }
            if (pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'jpg'){
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($basePath.'/'.$fileName);
                $width = imagesx($img);
                $height = imagesx($img);

                //Calculateing tumbnails size
                $newWidth = 100;
                $newHeight = floor($height*(100/$width));

                //Create a new tempoary image
                $tmpImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);

                imagecopyresized($tmpImage,$img,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);

                imagejpeg($tmpImage,$pathToTumb.'/'.$fileName);
            }
            if(pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'gif'){
                $img = imagecreatefromgif($basePath.'/'.$fileName);
                $width = imagesx($img);
                $height = imagesx($img);

                //Calculateing tumbnails size
                $newWidth = 100;
                $newHeight = floor($height*(100/$width));

                //Create a new tempoary image
                $tmpImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);

                imagecopyresized($tmpImage,$img,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);

                imagegif($tmpImage,$pathToTumb.'/'.$fileName);
            }
```

I find that very repetitive is there a different way to do this for different formats?

Also I want would to if it is even possible to do this when the image does not  have an extension for example if the name of the file is just test instead of test.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself copy and pasting code you should turn that code into a function.  Your code can be refactored as below:

```
switch (pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {
    case 'png':
        $tmpImage = thumb(imagecreatefrompng($basePath.'/'.$fileName));
        imagepng($tmpImage,$pathToTumb.'/'.$fileName);
        break;
    case 'jpg':
        $tmpImage = thumb(imagecreatefromjpeg($basePath.'/'.$fileName));
        imagejpeg($tmpImage,$pathToTumb.'/'.$fileName);
        break;
    case 'gif':
        $tmpImage = thumb(imagecreatefromgif($basePath.'/'.$fileName));
        imagegif($tmpImage,$pathToTumb.'/'.$fileName);
        break;
}

function thumb($img) {
    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesx($img);

    //Calculateing tumbnails size
    $newWidth = 100;
    $newHeight = floor($height*(100/$width));

    //Create a new tempoary image
    $tmpImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);

    imagecopyresized($tmpImage,$img,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);

    return $tmpImage;
}
```

For detecting the image type without a file extension you can use [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) or, if that is not available on your host, [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

Comment: The functions worked awesome! Thank you ill give the extenstion thing a try later on, Thank you for the help.